# how to fetch only recently added message in firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch recently added messages from database. But whenever I fetch those messages all messages are shown in recyclerview. I just want to show recently added messages.
//Here is my code -

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference uidRef = mDbReference.child("users").child(currentUser).
                child(selectedUser).child(ChatMessageModel.MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED);
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel = ds.getValue(ChatMessageModel.class);
                    messageList.add(chatMessageModel);
                }
                chatAppMsgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRecyclerview.setAdapter(chatAppMsgAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: ");
            }

        };
        uidRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);




     //here output like this -
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2mcE.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean through `recently added message`? Please also add your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Edit: Added Explanations

By using the reference in `uidRef`, you are retrieving all the data in that node of the firebase path.

To retrieve the last data added to that node in the database, you should add .limitToLast(1) method.

Check [Firebase Query - limitToLast()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Query#limitToLast)

Also, since you're retrieveing only one datum, you don't need to iterate, hence the removal of the forEach loop.

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    mDbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    final DatabaseReference uidRef = mDbReference.child("users").child(currentUser).
                            child(selectedUser).child(ChatMessageModel.MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED);
                    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel = ds.getValue(ChatMessageModel.class);
                            messageList.add(chatMessageModel);
                            chatAppMsgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mRecyclerview.setAdapter(chatAppMsgAdapter);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: ");
                        }

                    };
                    // Add the .limitToLast(1) query function or replace with the
                    // limitToFirst(1) if .limitToLast(1) didn't work
                    uidRef.limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```